# Stacking columns of vectors into single column of vectors

Tags: r, dataframe, stack

I am trying to stack columns `Vector1` and `Vector2` into a single column data frame `Test` using stack():

```
df = data.frame("Nr"=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10))
df$Vector1 <- list(as.numeric(c(123, 435 ,7)))
df$Vector2 <- list(as.numeric(c(234, 456, 4)))
Test <- stack(df[,2:3])[1]
```

When I use `stack()`, I get a single column data frame with 60 rows. However, I need `Test` to look like this:

```
c(123, 435 ,7)
c(123, 435 ,7)
c(123, 435 ,7)
c(123, 435 ,7)
c(123, 435 ,7)
c(123, 435 ,7)
c(123, 435 ,7)
c(123, 435 ,7)
c(123, 435 ,7)
c(123, 435 ,7)
c(234, 456, 4)
c(234, 456, 4)
c(234, 456, 4)
c(234, 456, 4)
c(234, 456, 4)
c(234, 456, 4)
c(234, 456, 4)
c(234, 456, 4)
c(234, 456, 4)
c(234, 456, 4)
```

Is there another way that I can accomplish this without the vectors being separated into 60 rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way with `unlist` :

```
result <- data.frame(id = seq(nrow(df) * 2))
result$stack_col <- unlist(df[2:3], recursive = FALSE, use.names = FALSE)
result

#   id   stack_col
#1   1 123, 435, 7
#2   2 123, 435, 7
#3   3 123, 435, 7
#4   4 123, 435, 7
#5   5 123, 435, 7
#6   6 123, 435, 7
#7   7 123, 435, 7
#8   8 123, 435, 7
#9   9 123, 435, 7
#10 10 123, 435, 7
#11 11 234, 456, 4
#12 12 234, 456, 4
#13 13 234, 456, 4
#14 14 234, 456, 4
#15 15 234, 456, 4
#16 16 234, 456, 4
#17 17 234, 456, 4
#18 18 234, 456, 4
#19 19 234, 456, 4
#20 20 234, 456, 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want a `matrix` of the `stack()$values` with number of columns corresponding to the length of an arbitrary element, e.g. the first `el`ement (assuming all lengths are equal).

```
matrix(stack(df[,2:3])$values, ncol=length(el(df$Vector1)), byrow=TRUE)
#       [,1] [,2] [,3]
#  [1,]  123  435    7
#  [2,]  123  435    7
#  [3,]  123  435    7
#  [4,]  123  435    7
#  [5,]  123  435    7
#  [6,]  123  435    7
#  [7,]  123  435    7
#  [8,]  123  435    7
#  [9,]  123  435    7
# [10,]  123  435    7
# [11,]  234  456    4
# [12,]  234  456    4
# [13,]  234  456    4
# [14,]  234  456    4
# [15,]  234  456    4
# [16,]  234  456    4
# [17,]  234  456    4
# [18,]  234  456    4
# [19,]  234  456    4
# [20,]  234  456    4
```